# How to resolve cyclical dependency in Angular 2 providers

Tags: angular, service, cyclic-dependency

I have multiple different services that extend another service:

```
BaseService {
    display(message: string): void { }
}

BetterService {
    constructor(private base: BaseService) { }

    display(message: string): void {
        this.base.display('Better ' + message);
    }
}
```

Now I configure them in AppModule like this:

```
imports: [
    DisplayModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: BetterService }
]
```

Obviously, Angular fails because when it tries to resolve BaseService needed for BetterService, it still uses BetterService (in an endless recursion). What can I do to make it work?

Comment: This is not exactly a cyclic dependency. What error do you get?

Comment: Can't resolve all parameters for BetterService: (?).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question it is marked as a duplicate of although the solution might be similar.  This question is about providing a BaseService to the BetterService, not really a cyclical dependency.  If BetterService is the only class that needs a BaseService, you could just create an instance of it in your constructor instead of relying on dependency injection.

Comment: I have a lot of modules that use BaseService. And I need to provide another service which will alter BaseService throughout the application using decorator pattern.